# how can I create a button grid in pyqt5 similar to a calculator

Tags: python-3.x, button, pyqt

I am working on my first GUI project in python, building a simple GUI calculator.
Rather than creating each button one by one I wanted to create them with two for loops
starting from this list of lists:

```
all_rows = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['0']]
```

my current goal is to place these buttons in a grid-like pattern, I tried to solve it as follows but i cannot figure out the error:

```
class MyWindow (QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

    #creating default width and height to work with a grid
    default_width = 50
    default_height = 50

    self.setGeometry(0, 0, 10*default_width, 10*default_height)
    self.setWindowTitle('Calcolatrice')
    self.InitUI()

def InitUI (self):

    all_rows = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['0']]
    bt_list = []

    #setting default height and width of buttons
    bt_width = 50
    bt_height = 50

    #looping troughout all_rows to create buttons
    for row in all_rows:
        for button in range(len(row)):

            #creating each button and giving it the name
            bt_list.append(QtW.QPushButton(self))
            bt_list[button].setText(row[button])
            bt_list[button].setGeometry(0,0,bt_width,bt_height)

            #setting button placement
            bt_list[button].move(bt_width * button, bt_height * all_rows.index(row))
```

i clearly did not expect this output, I cannot understand why only 8,9 and 0 are in the correct position

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Qt Main Window Framework
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework
>
> QMainWindow has its own layout
>
> Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder.

Try it:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(text, parent)

        self.setText(text)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 50))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(50, 50))
        

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.rows = 4
        self.columns = 3
        
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.label = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))

        self.layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        
        _list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
        len_list = len(_list)

        i = 0
        for row in range(self.rows): 
           for column in range(self.columns): 
                button = PushButton(f'{_list[i]}', self)
                button.clicked.connect(partial(self.onClicked, _list[i]))
                self.layout.addWidget(button, row+1, column)
                i += 1
                if i == len_list: break

    def onClicked(self, i):
        self.label.setNum(i)
        
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Calcolatrice')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]